# Sheet change event fires twice in Excel 2013, once in Excel 2010

Tags: excel-interop

Should an Excel 2010 addin project work in Excel 2013?

The reason I ask is because I created a project in Visual Studio 2010 for an Excel add-in which works fine in Excel 2010 but there are a lot of weird little bugs when it runs in Excel 2013. For example a sheet change event fires twice in Excel 2013 (it correctly fires once in Excel 2010).

Before I go down the route of re-building this project using the Excel 2013 addin template in Visual Studio I wanted to check if anyone else has come across this behaviour?